# Is method of generating sql query for orderby changed between tiny_tds 0.2.3 and 0.4.3

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, tiny-tds

I had **rails 3.0.1 and tiny_tds 0.2.3 and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.0.7** and the query below was working fine. After upgrading to 
 **rails 3.0.20, tiny_tds 0.4.3, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.0.19** it stopped working due to order by clause.

There is a table **events** with a column **starts_at** which is of type **datetime**.

**Ruby code:**

> @events = Event.where("archived = 'False' and starts_at >= ? and
>   event_company_id in (1,2,3)", start_date).select(" distinct  top(14)
>   convert(date, starts_at, 112) as start_date").order("convert(date,
>   starts_at, 112)")

**used to generate a sql query as follows:**

> SELECT distinct top(14) convert(date, starts_at, 112) as start_date
>   FROM [events] WHERE (archived = 'False' and starts_at >= '2013-02-04'
>   and event_company_id in (1,2,3)) ORDER BY convert(date, starts_at,
>   112)

**but now, the query being generated is :**

> SELECT  distinct  top(14) convert(date, starts_at, 112) as start_date
>   FROM [events] WHERE (archived = 'False' and starts_at >= '2013-02-05'
>   and event_company_id in (1,2,3)) ORDER BY convert(date ASC, starts_at
>   ASC, 112) ASC

Note the part around order by:

> **ORDER BY convert(date ASC, starts_at ASC, 112) ASC**
>
> **instead of ORDER BY convert(date, starts_at, 112)**

Due to this, I am getting the following error:

> **TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ASC'.:**

Is there some change in syntax that needs to be followed for such queries or are the versions that I am using not correct? I had to upgrade tiny_tds and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter as a part of migrating from rails 3.0.1 to rails 3.0.20

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as of 3.0.8 there is monkey patching to attempt to fix the way Arel parses the order by clause: 
[class SelectManager, method order(*expr)](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/blob/3.0.8/lib/arel/visitors/sqlserver.rb)

If you pass in a string to the order clause it will simply split the string by commas in order to get an array of column names.  If you are ordering by a function then it will totally ruin the order by clause.  The good news is that you can prevent this failed splitting by passing something like this to the order clause instead:

```
order(
  Arel::Nodes::Ordering.new(
    Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("convert(date, starts_at, 112)")
  )
)
```

The function call will be passed to the sql statement builder as-is